# line.seperator does not replace \n

Tags: java, cross-platform, newline

Say I have a TextArea for users to input. And it is multilined.

So, I write the following text into it.

> "Testing line
>    and line and
>    line"

Well, something to be reminded here. To put line separator, user only presses **Enter**. Now, I want to replace all the line separators from the input text with "**!**". I expect the output to be

> "Testing!line!and!line!and!line"

In order to do this, I used the following code.

```
System.out.println(getText().replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "!"));
```

However, the output is the same as the input text. But, if I replace the above code with

```
System.out.println(getText().replace("\n", "!"));
```

The output turns out to be as expected.

Consider this as OS-independent. I tested this under Windows XP.

How can I replace **\n** with something that is able to run in different OS. It is supposed to be **System.getProperty("line.separator")** but I don't get why it doesn't work here.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this input through a Java thing such as Swing/JavaFX or through a native Windows thing such as the console? (sorry, brain is too fried to think of a more fitting word than "thing") If memory serves, Java should use `\n` internally, so you might not need the `line.separator` property as long as you don't interact with any native Windows components. Not 100% sure about that though.

Comment: To clarify: Are you expecting this "Testing line!and line and!line" or this "Testing!line!and!line!and!line"?

Comment: @Laambi My bad. Spaces are fine for now. Line separators trouble here. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Document` of a JTextArea (or JTextPane) always stores the newline string as "\n". So, when using a `JTextArea` the following code will work on all platforms:

```
System.out.println(getText().replace("\n", "!"));
```

However if you use the `textArea.write(...)` method, the "\n" will be replaced by the "line.separator" for your platform.

Check out [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) which attempts to explain this behaviour in more detail.

Comment: Does that mean using JTextArea or JTextPane in any platform will store the line separator as "\n" regardless of OS property?

Comment: Yes, the Document doesn't care about the OS property.

Comment: That answers my question. But, I am actually writing a library. JTextArea was just to test it. What if later someone uses with some other input components? Not swing. How can I guarantee that it will work?

Comment: `That answers my question.` - then the answer should be accepted, so people know that an answer has been found. `How can I guarantee that it will work?`  Your question doesn't make sense. You can't guarantee anything is someone changes your code.

Comment: This is a library I am writing. In this library, there is a function which simply replaces line.separator with another CharSequence. JTextArea was to test this function. But if someone uses this(as library/.jar), with non-swing input component, how can I assure that the function will still replace the line.separator? Because you said in swing the line separator is not line.separator property. It is always \n character.

Comment: `But if someone uses this(as library/.jar), with non-swing input component, how can I assure that the function will still replace the line.separator?` If somebody uses a non JTextComponent, how will your code know how to get the text from the component? How do you know what method to invoke on that component? I don't understand your design so I can't help.

Comment: No No, the function itself only takes **String**. Nothing to do with Swing. To test this function, in another application, I feed this String from JTextArea. So, my question is, what if someone else feed String to this function from a non-swing component. Could I make my point?